# How can I avoid that the app crashes when I try to load data and the app has no internet?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was trying to solve it by using a try/catch function but I get the error..

> Cannot implicity convert type bool to NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

..when I try to return false on the catch. This is the code:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();
        try {

            //connection
            var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("localhost");

            var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

            var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

            return jsonResult;

        } catch {
        //no connection
            return false; //ERROR: Cannot implicity convert type bool to NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
        }

    }
```

Comment: You want to `return null` instead - you're trying to return `false` when your function says it returns `Task<JObject>`, which is the source of the compiler error.

Comment: @David T. Macknet When I return Null, and turn off wifi and use the app I get the error on the page that loads data: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your method signature is

```
static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
```

so you can't return a bool on the catch.  You have to return a JObject, or null.

Comment: When I return Null, and turn off wifi and use the app I get the error on the page that loads data: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: If you are returning a null, then the code that is calling the getInfo() method needs to be able to handle a null.  Perhaps check for a null result, and display a message to the user "data is not available right now"?

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Now i get it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

`JObject` is an actual *object*. `bool` is not an object.

You can, however, return `JToken`:

```
static public async Task<JToken> GetInfoAsync()
{
  var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();
  try {
    ...
  } catch {
    //no connection
    return new JValue(false);
  }
}
```

I also renamed your method to `GetInfoAsync` to follow the [appropriate naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: He's one of my favorite authors!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean `return null`?  The compiler is complaining because your method claims to return a `Task<JObject>` and you're trying to return a `bool` value.

(Obviously, if you return `null`, you'll have to make sure the calling code knows what to do in that instance.  Another option is to allow the exception to be thrown and catch it higher up.)

Answer (score 0):

The proper thing to do would be to throw an `Exception` and catch it in the UI layer and display an alert to the user.

You could also just do this: `return default(JObject);` instead of `return false;`

Comment: when I turn of my wifi and try to load data in the app, i get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I use return default (JObject)